# Inheritance base class reference C#

Tags: c#, inheritance, reference, base-class

```
class Base
    {
        //...
        public int i = 5;
    }

class Drifted : Base
{
    //...
    public int b = 10;
}

Base ObjectOrReference = new Drifted();
```

So `Base ObjectOrReference;`is reference to the base type.
When we write `Base ObjectOrReference = new Drifted();` it becomes object because by using 'new' we allocate memory for it? Or it still reference and if it is true, what type does it have?
Direct question is: "Is `ObjectOrReference` object?"

Comment: Could you please rephrase your question?

Comment: Basically I was asked Does 'ObjectOrReference' reference OR object ? As I understand it simultaneously reference and and limited object of 'Drifted' class by limited I mean it has access only to members defined in 'Base'.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's still a reference, a pointer to the object on the heap.  It is of type `Drifted`.

Even though your reference is of the `Base` type, the underlying object is `Drifted` and any overridden members in the derived class `Drifted` will be used instead of those on `Base`, even though you are trying to use `Base`.

In the case of member hiding using the `new` syntax, if you have a reference to the base type it will bypass any derived classes that are hiding the members.

An overview can be found online with Googling for "C# Reference Types".  I skimmed this, looks like a worthwhile read:

http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx

Comment: Why I can assign value to the 'ObjectOrReference.i' And what is the name that object in heap if 'ObjectOrReferenc' is not object.

Comment: @Nikita because that is a member of the `Base` type.  Using the `ObjectOrReference` local variable you cannot see `Drifted.b`, you would need to cast to `Drifted` to see that.

Comment: @Nikita C# hides the fact that it's actually pointing to a memory location on the heap.  C# references are automatically resolved to the object for you, whereas in C++ you would need to resolve the pointer yourself.

Answer (score 7):

```
Base ObjectOrReference = new Drifted();
```

with that, you have created a `Drifted` instance but is referenced by `Base` reference variable `ObjectOrReference`. Right now it's capabilities are limited to that of what's available in `Base`. If you want to, say access `int b` in `Drifted`, you'll have to cast it to `Drifted`

Answer (score 7):

Yes, `ObjectOrReference` is an object and a valid object.

It is an object of `Drifted` Type. It is a basic concept of Object Oriented Programming that  pointer/ref of base class(`ObjectOrReference` in your case) can hold/refer to object of it's derived classes(`Drifted` in your case) thats why it is not an error and a valid object of `Drifted` type

Answer (score 6):

It is and always be a reference. Think of object variables as pointers/refernces. While the actual object creation/allocation happens on heap, references are created on local stack space.

Answer (score 1):

You have instantiated the object of a derived class but are refering to its memory location through its
base class reference type (ObjectOrReference). Object reference knows the member of its type only (i.e with in its base class) and is completely unaware about the member of its derived class.
So you can't access the member of an derived class and you can't type cast here as we are talking about inheritance